# Ways to make a broker at Azure for anonymous HTTP API messages?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus

We need API at Azure that would store messages sent to it (broker) via HTTP in case my system (Cloud Service) unavailable or DB is busy. It's not easy to change what exact message will be sent. What ways to make such a broker at Azure?

Service Bus Queue looks interesting but it needs [Shared Access Signatures](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest/) as far as I understand.

Another WebRole should be a solution but it needs time to implement.

Virtual Machine with some tool (MSMQ?) seems a way but it requires maintenance.

What do you think?

Comment: you can store those messages in queues or even blob storage and have a function app being triggered by the message as an event and then work on that message and send it to wherever you want..

Comment: @Aravind How would I store in queues (Service Bus, right?) them at first if I can't modify my clients? Thanks!

Comment: it can be service bus or storage queues. you have to at least modify your client app to send the message to a particular new endpoint .

Comment: Storage Queues or Azure Service Bus Queues, both will use Primary Key or Secodary Key in order to access and send/receive messages. I'll recommend Service Bus Queues because they can guarantee FIFO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario is a prime candidate for applying a **Queue-Centric Work Pattern**.

From http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/queue-centric-work-pattern:

[image: Loosely Coupled]

If either your Worker(s) or Database become unavailable, messages are still placed in durable storage and consumed later.

The **Task Queue** can take the form of an Azure Storage Queue or a Service Bus Queue. In every great design, the least complex component that does the job wins. In this case that would be Azure Storage Queues, durable, reliable, very few moving parts. Unless you absolutely need precision FIFO ordering, in which case you go with Service Bus.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568101.aspx:

> This solution offers the following benefits:
>
> - It enables an inherently load-leveled system that can handle wide variations in the volume of requests sent by application instances. The queue acts as a buffer between the application instances and the consumer service instances, which can help to minimize the impact on availability and responsiveness for both the application and the service instances (as described by the Queue-based Load Leveling pattern). Handling a message that requires some long-running processing to be performed does not prevent other messages from being handled concurrently by other instances of the consumer service.
> - It improves reliability. If a producer communicates directly with a consumer instead of using this pattern, but does not monitor the consumer, there is a high probability that messages could be lost or fail to be processed if the consumer fails. In this pattern messages are not sent to a specific service instance, a failed service instance will not block a producer, and messages can be processed by any working service instance.
> - It does not require complex coordination between the consumers, or between the producer and the consumer instances. The message queue ensures that each message is delivered at least once.
> - It is scalable. The system can dynamically increase or decrease the number of instances of the consumer service as the volume of messages fluctuates.
> - It can improve resiliency if the message queue provides transactional read operations. If a consumer service instance reads and processes the message as part of a transactional operation, and if this consumer service instance subsequently fails, this pattern can ensure that the message will be returned to the queue to be picked up and handled by another instance of the consumer service.

Answer (score 1):

Given you can't change the client, I would proxy the call. Recreate the API using the API Management Service in Azure, and change the web url to point to the API Management Service proxy.

The proxy can then easily delegate to a [function application](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-create-an-event-processing-function/) like Aravind mentioned in the comments to your question by using the [API Management Service policies.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/AzureApiMgmt/Policy-Expressions-in-Azure-API-Management)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to API Management Service and to function applications. So far we don't have much load. It seems API Management Service would complicate things and add cost. So Queue-Centric Work Pattern when webrole acting as a proxy for those calls looks enough.

Comment: Prefer not to use WebRole. It's ASM/Classic Azure, so you'd be writing legacy. Azure is moving to ARM/Resource manager. Cloud Service becomes AppService. Also, if you can run Developer SKU, you can run it at less than the cost of App Service. Replace Web-Role with API Management Service, and use the same Queue-Centric Work pattern. It is simpler to write a policy for API Management than it is to write the code for a web role. (You just have to spend a few hours learning it). Whichever way you choose, I hope it goes well.